# Selenium IDE Load Text From File

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-ide

I have installed Selenium IDE for Chrome as well as Selenium Side Runner, NodeJS, and ChromeDriver.  I am able to successfully create a .side project and run it against a website.  However, I have not been able to figure out how to read text from a txt file (just a single numeral in this case) and insert it into a form field on a site.  I have previous experience with iMacros, so I attempted to use some of that knowledge to get Selenium to read the file but with no luck.  If I edit the .side file in Notepad++, it is mostly just css with embedded commands, so I am really not sure of next steps.  Any assistance would be appreciated.